# Continuing userActivity while app I closed

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, nsuseractivity

I am trying to implement universal linking into my app using the `AppDelegate` class. It is working perfectly fine when the app is already open in the background, but it is acting strange while the app is NOT in the background, specifically it will only work 1 time if the app is not in the background. For example: When I boot up my app for the first time, multi-task then swipe out of the app I can click a link and it will navigate to the correct place in the app. If I try that again it will not work, but If I reboot the app it will work once again. Keep in mind if the app is in the background the universal linking will work every time.

Here is what my `AppDelegate` looks like:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        
        if let url = userActivity.webpageURL {
            self.continueWithLink(url: url)
        }
        return true
    }
```

in `didFinsihLaunchingWithOptions` function:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        if let url = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.url] as? URL {
            self.continueWithLink(url: url)
        } else {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarViewController")
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
```

The `continueWithLink` function will decipher where the link is wanting to navigate to and then will call a function that sets the desired viewController like this:

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        if let _ = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? BannedViewController { return }
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: nil)
        let profileVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileView") as! ProfileViewController
        profileVC.shouldNavigateToHome = true
        profileVC.shouldNavigateToHomeAction = {
            self.loadMainStoryboard()
        }
        
        let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: profileVC)
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navigationVC
        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: like on yesterdays question: do you really intend to return here: `if let _ = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? BannedViewController { return }` and like yesterday: deriving truth from the state of the ui is a very dangerous thing to do.